# React search highlighing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a search that highlights the matching characters within the displayed list.

I having trouble figuring out how I can add a DOM node within a list as it is being created/updated. The following code is where I got to. I think I understand why its not working (i keep getting 'Stephine Ma[object Object]ks'as the output). I am fairly sure I need to add it as an actual DOM node using .HTMl or .innerHTML but with react im not sure how one would do that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

export default class extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        var divImage = {
            backgroundImage : "url(" + this.props.image + ")"
        };
        var test = this.props.name;

        if(this.props.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) != -1 ) {
            var pattern = this.props.filterText.toString();
            test = test.replace(pattern, <span className="highlight">+pattern+</span>)
        }
        return (
            <li className="panelItem">
                <a className="item-title" style={divImage}>{test}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example if you can use indexOf instead of regex matching. Builds all the nodes and wraps them in spans.

https://jsfiddle.net/2zx84koy/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var name = this.props.name;
        var startIdx = name.indexOf(this.props.filterText);
        var textNodes = <span>{name}</span>

        if(startIdx > -1 ) {
          textNodes = (
            <span>
                {name.substring(0, startIdx)}
                <span className="highlight">{name.substring(startIdx, startIdx + this.props.filterText.length)}</span>
                {name.substring(startIdx + this.props.filterText.length)}
            </span>

          )
        }


        return (
            <li className="panelItem">
                <a className="item-title">{textNodes}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

You can do innerHTML in react but in general its not advised unless you know for sure it would not leave you vulnerable to xss attacks. I put an example below of how to convert your code to that style just for reference.

```
var test = this.props.name;

if(this.props.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) != -1 ) {
    var pattern = this.props.filterText.toString();
    test = test.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlight">' + pattern + '</span>')
}


return (
    <li className="panelItem">
        <a className="item-title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: test}}></a>
    </li>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a huge help to getting my project working as well as to understanding how to do it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar quite recently, I created a library ([prelude-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prelude-extension)) and a component ([react-selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-selectize)) for it, here's a [demo](http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/?category=simple&example=search-highlighting), maybe it is what you are looking for.